# Background thread vs UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Could any one help me to figure out background thread and UI thread in C#.I have googled it but i coudnt find article illustrate both.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A UI thread creates UI elements and waits and responds to events like mouse clicks and key presses. You can only access the UI elements from the UI thread.

There are two types of threads: background and foreground. A UI thread is an example of a foreground thread.

The difference between background and foreground threads is pretty simple. Background threads don't stop a process from terminating, but foreground threads do. When the last foreground thread stops, then all the background threads are also stopped and the process ends.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,in deed ur comment was really helps to me

Answer (score 7):

This website has a lot of information about threading as well as parallel programming: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

There is another key issue to keep in mind. There is a single U.I. thread and you can only call methods on U.I. objects in that thread. In another thread you need to call Control.Invoke() to flip to the U.I. thread if you are doing something like update a status bar.